# path based routing in ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services

we have a scenario where we need to route http://xyz.xyz.com/api/users/Validate to http://xyz.xyz.com/api/Users/Validate (Only difference here is caps U)
We have been forwarding path bassed routing using Application load balancer to the target groups.
But not sure how can we redirect in the above case.
Can someone please guide?

Thanks

Tried forwarding to the target group but that does not solve the purpose since we need to redirect

Answer (score 0):

few ways to handle routing HTTP requests with different casing in the path to the same backend target in an ALB:

1. Use path-based routing rules with a wildcard () in the path pattern. For example, route /api/users/ to the target group. This will match /api/users/Validate and /api/Users/Validate.
2. Use a Lambda function with the ALB to rewrite the incoming request path to standard casing before forwarding to the target.
3. Handle the casing difference in your application code instead of at the load balancer level. For example, normalize the path to lowercase before routing.
4. Use an API Gateway in front of the ALB and define casing-insensitive resource paths there.
5. Redirect HTTP requests with different casing to a canonical format using 301 redirects. For example redirect /api/Users/Validate to /api/users/Validate.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please explain the point 5 how this can be achieved?
I added a rule in the Listener with HOST header and the path pattern matching /api/users* to redirect to the Full URL

Comment: For this rule, you'll set it to redirect using a 301 permanent redirect to the lowercase version of the path. There's a couple ways to convert the path to lowercase:

You could use a Lambda function that takes in /api/Users/Validate and returns /api/users/Validate. This lets you programmatically change the case.
Or just manually construct the lowercase path by replacing the first segment with the lowercase version, like /api/users/{match.path[0]}. This just hardcodes it.